# How do I use cURL to get a response from a website and then run that response as python?

Tags: python, batch-file, curl

For my batch file I want to have a command that will allow me to use 2 parameters, `(language) (url)`, and have the ability to run the the **URL** in whatever language I like. What I mean by this is that lets say there's a **URL** called `https://mycode.com/mycode`, and its response is `print("hello")`. I would like to be able to be able to input `python https://mycode.com/mycode` into my batch terminal and it would run whatever the response is in python. I already know how to make multiple parameters, I just need to know how I can get the response and run it with python in one automated process. Similar to **LUA** and how you can do `loadstring("url")` and it will run the response in **LUA**.

Also: `I mainly would like to run the response in python but with the multiple parameters I'm hoping I can choose the language I want to run the response in depending on what the response is.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I solved it (kinda). I used a simple line to get the response of the website and then wrote it onto a file. Then I made my batch script run the file.

Heres my batch code:

```
IF /i "%1"=="python" (
ECHO %1 %2>>commandslog.log"
curl %2 > requiredfile.py
echo.
python3 requiredfile.py
echo.
goto :EOF
)
```

Output:

```
pog@DESKTOP-FRHIDN2-D:\Management\Documents\calardian:~$ python https://pastebin.com/raw/LXyvev8g

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    14    0    14    0     0     14      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   128

hello

pog@DESKTOP-FRHIDN2-D:\Management\Documents\calardian:~$
```

So It ran the hello script from the website, however I don't know why it shows all those stats above `hello` I dont want that there and I don't know if its cURL or the python.